# Data type Mismatch in criterion expression

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm entirely new to SQL and keep getting an data type mismatch in criterion expression. Trying to figure out where to make the changes.

```
SELECT AVG(Price)
FROM Book, OrderLine, [Order]
WHERE OrderDeliveryDate > '2016/05/05' and Order.OrderNo = OrderLine.OrderNo and Book.ISBN = OrderLine.ISBN and PercentageDiscount = 'NULL';
```

Comment: can you please share more details like the column of tables,and your expectation on the output?

Comment: Based on filtering criteria I think it's better if you can use joins.

Comment: Trying to obtain the average price before discount of all the books that were delivered after May 5, 2016

Comment: can u share the details of the tables you are using?which tables  have the 'price' ,OrderDeliveryDate ,PercentageDiscount columns?

Comment: Book - ISBN, Title, Category, Stock, Price, Used / OrderLine - OrderNo, OrderRank, ISBN, Quantity, Percentage Discount / Order - OrderNo, OrderDate, OrderDeliveryDate, CustomerID

Comment: I'd suggest to try it without WHERE first - most likely there will be no error, and then try each expression in WHERE to figure out the concrete reason

Comment: Please read [this](https://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/) for some tips on improving your question. Without the DDL we can't tell what the data types ought to be.

Comment: Thank you for all of the suggestions. Still new to this, but all replies are truly helpful

Answer (score 1):

Try using the `INNER JOIN` syntax and the correct data types:

```sql
SELECT 
    AVG(Price)
FROM 
    ([Order]
INNER JOIN
    OrderLine ON [Order].OrderNo = OrderLine.OrderNo)
INNER JOIN
    Book ON OrderLine.ISBN = Book.ISBN
WHERE 
    OrderDeliveryDate > #2016/05/05# And 
    PercentageDiscount Is Null;
```